# how to make few child nodes as parent's attributes in xsl? xslt for this

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml format

```
<A>
 <a>1</a>
 <b>2</b>
 <c>3</c>
 ........
 ........
</A>
```

I want to format it as

```
 <A a="1" b="2">
 <c>3</c> 
 .........
</A>
```

note: I want only first few say 2 children to convert as parent's attributes ,not all.

The xsl which know for converting all attributes is

```
  <xsl:template match="A">
  <A> 
     <xsl:for-each select="*">
       <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"> 
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> 
       </xsl:attribute> 
     </xsl:for-each> 
  <A> 
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: did you try anything, or are you waiting for others to do your homework?

Comment: i tried! I know how to make all nodes as attributes but in this case, I want only few to add in parent'node.By the way I am new to XML, I am a SAS programmer actually and have not met this situation earlier.

Comment: Why don't you post what you have, so we can correct it instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: <xsl:template match="A">
     <A>
       <xsl:for-each select="*">
         <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
           <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:for-each>
     <A>
     </xsl:template>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some positional predicates:

```
<xsl:template match="A">
    <A> 
        <xsl:for-each select="*[position() &lt;= 2]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> 
            </xsl:attribute> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[position() > 2]"/>
    </A> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: i am unable to open file that was created using the above template.it says-Invalid at the top level of the document.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Here's a working demo: http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38YE